# Is it possible to delete or overwrite cmdlets?

Tags: powershell

I'm working with DNS resource records in Powershell 5 using code that I inherited from the guy who was trying to do this before me. The cmdlet I am trying to use is `Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA`.

Part of his code has  `import-module certain folder\PowerShell\Modules\DnsServer`. The weird thing is, it seems like as I was trying bits and pieces of the code earlier, I was able to use the add-DNSblah cmdlet. Now, after It ried running the whole script including the import-module, Powershell is saying that the cmdlet does not exist natively, and when I import the module and run it it is giving me `Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA: Invalid Class`.

It is my understanding that Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA should be included in my normal Powershell 5.0. Could that Import-Module have permanently damaged PS somehow? Why else would the cmdlet not show up, even in a Get-Command "*dns*"?

Comment: Hi, what is the OS? Does `import-module certain folder\PowerShell\Modules\DnsServer` succeed?

Comment: Does cmdlet not work in fresh clean PowerShell session? Does command show up with `Get-Command *dns*`?

Comment: OS is Windows 10 Enterprise. Import-Module does succeed. The command does not show up with `Get-Command "*dns*"` in a clean session until the module is imported, but my understanding is that it should. Either way, once the module is imported, I get an Invalid Class error. `FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA`     The command does not ever work, whether in a clean session or after import

Comment: You are right, I think you should have the cmdlet natively. Maybe try to reinstall/update PowerShell? Or on another workstation? Could this be related to RSAT somehow?

Comment: I just checked on my home computer, which is Windows 10 running powershell 5, and it does not have the cmdlet either. That's weird, because it seems like it should, but maybe I'm just barking up the wrong tree. @sodawillow

Comment: shouldn't it come with the dns server role?

Comment: As @sodawillow touched on, this will likely be because the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) need to be installed before you will be able to import the dns cmdlets natively. Download here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=45520 Once these are insalled you will be able to run `Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA` without having to manually import the `DnsServer` Module everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you will need the **Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT)** installed to have these cmdlets available on a non-server Windows OS.

You can download them from this page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=45520.

Not really sure why the `Import-Module` does not fail if the `DNSServer` module is not present on the system.

If RSAT are already installed, you can try to reinstall them.

Comment: That was it. I'm not sure how I missed that, whether it was not obvious or I was just oblivious, but thanks for the tip! There was a DNSServer "module" present, but I think it only had some cmdlet definitions, and didn't have the classes needed to do the work. I'm not even sure how the guy found the DNSSever module to begin with... Anyway, thanks for you help!